# IntelliJ IDEA Community e uso de banco de dados

Tags: java, ide

Galera, estou pensando em utilizar a IntelliJ IDEA Community para desenvolver em Java, mas vi que essa versão não tem ferramentas para banco de dados. Vi no site mas não ficou claro quanto a isso.

Alguém trabalha com essa versão que possa me ajudar a entender as limitações que há em relação a banco de dados?
Grato!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Community não tem ferramentas para manipular o BD no próprio software. Mas vc consegue trabalhar com ele tranquilamente usando o SGBD da sua escolha.

Comment: Entendi, vlw ai!!!